# Python Google API for elaborate query

Tags: python, google-api

I'm looking for an Google API for python (except the official API), in order to make "eloborate" query like "intitle", "intext","filetype", ...

I made some research on the internet but I don't have find my need. Maybe I misssearched or maybe that doesn't exist.

Can you give me some lead or advice ?

Thank you.

Comment: Explain exactly what you want ot query. The Google search engine ? Google Drive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Search API has deprecated long ago. You could use something like [pygoogle](https://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/) to screen-scrape the results page, but you're liable to be detected by Google's anti-bot captchas if you make a large number of queries.

Comment: I have already look into pygoogle, but I don't have found the option to use "intitle", "intext","filetype".